# How to repair grout detaching from bathroom floor/shower base junction

Tags: shower, floor, grout, gap, silicone

I recently bought a condo and noticed that the grout between the bathroom floor and the shower is detaching from the tiles and shower base (see photos). I'm wondering what is the best way to repair this so it doesn't fail again:

- Should I re-grout or put silicone instead?
- If putting silicone

  - Can I put it directly on the old grout or is it preferable to remove the old grout before?
  - If removing the old grout, do I need to install a backer rod given that the gap would be ~5/16'' ?

[image: Detaching grout at floor/shower base junction]

[image: Detaching grout at floor/shower base junction (closer look)]

Comment: That shouldn't have been grout. Sometimes the wrong type of caulk gets used in spots like that and it's more likely to fail. I see little stretches here and there, where that's not a grout thing. You want to remove the old gunk and replace it with silicone. I think I can see a bit of brown ceramic at a floor tile grout line, but just to be sure, that's a tile floor? And how big is that gap going to be after the old gunk has been removed?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yeah looks like there's more than grout. It's a tile floor, and the gap is going to be 5/16''

Comment: That's not grout, it's caulk.  But not the right kind of caulk—could be an acrylic type.  Remove as much as you can and apply a pure silicone type.  Might be worth using some backer rod...hard to tell how big the gap is in a photo.

Comment: There's clearly been movement in the shower base. Any idea why?

Comment: @Huesmann the gap would be 5/16'', I edited the post accordingly

Comment: @isherwood not sure what happened exactly. The building is only a few years old so maybe settling during the first years? Also, the shower is against an exterior wall and we get big shifts in temperature / humidity between the summer and winter